# Is there a way to find the deleted transactions by list Id?

Tags: quickbooks, qbfc

My goal is to find the deleted transactions during a period of the time for a list of jobs. The period of the time can be different from job to job. I am currently using TxnDeletedQueryRq but the request only provides filter on date range. I tried to look into other requests, but no luck so far. I am wondering if anyone knows a way to achieve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I can think of would be to create an audit trail report and parse for the state "Deleted". This allows you to set an entity filter for the name, plus you could set the modified date range an the report period to maybe help narrow down the information you would need to parse:

```
IGeneralDetailReportQuery report = MsgRequest.AppendGeneralDetailReportQueryRq();
report.DisplayReport.SetValue(false);
report.GeneralDetailReportType.SetValue(ENGeneralDetailReportType.gdrtAuditTrail);

report.ReportEntityFilter.ORReportEntityFilter.FullNameList.Add("Customer");

report.ORReportPeriod.ReportPeriod.FromReportDate.SetValue(fromDate);
report.ORReportPeriod.ReportPeriod.ToReportDate.SetValue(toDate);

report.ORReportModifiedDate.ReportModifiedDateRangeFilter.FromReportModifiedDate.SetValue(fromModDate);
report.ORReportModifiedDate.ReportModifiedDateRangeFilter.ToReportModifiedDate.SetValue(toModDate);
```